# Accessing Images in PowerPoint file via VSTO Add-In (C#)

Tags: c#, vsto, powerpoint

I am trying to build a PowerPoint add-in that will allow me to do a one-click optimization of the current presentation by removing unused master slides and converting huge 24-bit PNG files to slightly-compressed JPGs.

I have the first part handled already, and now I'm working on the images. Although I can easily find the Shape object containing the image, I cannot find a way to access the source image through the managed API. At best, I can copy the shape to the clipboard, which **does** give me the image but in a different format (MemoryBmp).

```
using PPTX = Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint;

...

foreach (PPTX.Slide slide in Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActivePresentation.Slides)
{
    foreach (PPTX.Shape shape in slide.Shapes)
    {
        if (shape.Type == MsoShapeType.msoPicture)
        {
            // Now, how can I access the source image contained within this shape?

            // I -can- copy it via the clipboard, like this:
            shape.Copy();
            System.Drawing.Image image = Clipboard.GetImage();

            // ...but image's format reflects a MemoryBmp ImageFormat, as noted here: 
            // https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Drawing/commonui/System/Drawing/Advanced/ImageFormat.cs
            // ...which doesn't help me determine if the source image is something that should be optimized.
        }
    }
}
```

Obviously, I can get to the images directly via other methods (e.g. accessing the contents of the file as a ZIP, or using OpenXML SDK), but I'm trying to perform all the steps from within the already-opened presentation (which means I can't update the open file). Any thoughts on how I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Shape` `Export` function.

```
void Export(string PathName, PpShapeFormat Filter, int ScaleWidth = 0, int ScaleHeight = 0, PpExportMode ExportMode = PpExportMode.ppRelativeToSlide)
```

There is a very little documentation of this function.
I've found it in the `Shape` interface definition.
So your code would look something like:

```
shape.Export(<some_file>, PpShapeFormat.ppShapeFormatPNG);
```

[More info on MSDN](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2007-customize/exporting-embedded-images-from-powerpoint-2007/cb2c0977-89cc-4bac-bcae-47bb18547045?db=5)

Comment: Export will let me export either format, regardless of what the original version is, though. It will not tell me that the original source image was PNG or JPG, or what the original size was, so I can't be certain whether an image needs to be optimized or not.